# How to always "Show all affected files" from "Version Control" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea

I can remember when using Jetbrains Rubymine and clicked on "show svn history" I was able to see all affected files of each commit directly by selecting the commit, I guess they have been preloaded

in IntelJ IDEA I have to always ask for it.

Is it possible to do this and how?